# Get the selected checkbox names from Child to Parent React

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that collects the selected names of the checkboxes. Now I need to pass the names to the parent component to use in future functions. Following is my code. the **parent** is a class component & **child** is a functional component.

**Parent**

```
<SandLite />
```

**Child**

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        let isChecked = e.target.checked;
        seats.push(e.target.name)
        if(isChecked){
            alert(seats);
        }else{
            seats = seats.filter((name) => e.target.name !== name);
            alert("removed",e.target.name)
        }
    console.log(seats)
}
```

now I want to pass the seats array to my parent called

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks and props

Firstly, define seats array in the parent component,

> it's better to define it using `useState()`.

Then add handleOnchange function inside the parent component.

Inside the child component tag define a prop and call it any name, say `handleSelected` and another prop call it `list`. To be like this:

Now, inside the child component, define the `props` as an argument. Then assign `props.handleSelected` to the `onChange` attribute in the input tag to be like : `onChange={props.handleSelected`}

That's it.

Comment: can you please show how to define the props as an argument

Comment: const Child = (props) => {  //code block  }

Comment: still im struggling on this. can you check on this https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-worker-2j9144?file=/src/theater.js

Comment: check sandbox now, please.